# How fix lengthen tile created by geo tools?

Tags: gdal, geotools, gdal2tiles

I use [gdal2tiles.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html) for creating tiles from a tif with `EPSG:4326`. The geotiff information in qgis is as follow:
[image: Geotiff information]

For zoom=0, x=0 and y=0 it create a tile as follow:

[image: Tile z=0&x=0&y=0, created by gdal]

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/coverage/coverage.html) to creating tiles with geotools(with Bbox: [-180, -90, 180, 90]), but the output is as follow:

[image: tile created by geotools]

I want to show the tiles in openlayers. But tiles are long in y direction.
**What's the problem? Why is the tile long? What is there that I have not considered?**

Comment: because it should be half as high as it is wide - -180,180 vs. -90,90

Comment: No, Look at the gdal2tiles.py [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Ho7.png)

Comment: but they are in different projections - the top one is 3857 and the bottom one is 4326 (which is half as high as it is wide)

Comment: @IanTurton But the source file is the same for both(When I open source file with qgis, the project is `EPSG:43261`)

Comment: can you add to your question exactly what your input file is and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @IanTurton I updated the question